# Random timeouts in PROD server with axios, but working normally on POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, api, server, axios, timeout

I'm using axios to call a simple API. It is working fine in Postman and DEV environment (300~700ms response time). The problem is that in production, a lot of requests is throwing timeout error. I set the timeout in 30 seconds. This problem does not occur in dev environment neither in Postman. It is the only API that is having this problem. I thought it was rate limiting problem, but they said that the amount of requests that I'm doing should not have problems.

I'm using axios v0.21.2 and apollo-server-express to build my server. It is running in GCP.

The code is only a GET request to the API using AxiosInstance.

[I changed the timeout time to 2000ms. My log in gcloud is like this now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfUTa.png)

I made a runner test in Postman with 1000~2000 requests and got 0 timeouts. Did some k6 tests on DEV with 2 requests/second and 0 timeouts too.

No matter the timeout configured on axios, it never gets the response and throws a timeout. But is random. If I call my server in postman, sometimes it returns a valid response or gets a timeout and or a lot of timeouts in a row.

I don't know what to search/test anymore to fix it.